# How to map 2 objects using MapStruct in a Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapping, mapstruct

I have a Spring Boot project and I'm using mapstruct to map 2 objects.
And I have this king of structure, this is the first object:

```
ObjectA {
List<ObjectB> objectsB;
}

ObjectB {
String prId;
List<String> dtId;
}

---
```

The second object:

```
ObjectC {
List<ObjectD> objectsD;
}

ObjectD {
ObjectE objectE;
List<ObjectE> objectsE;
}

ObjectE {
String nmId;
}
```

And now using mapstruct I need to do this:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface AppMapper {
    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "objectC.objectsD.objectE.nmId", source = "objectA.objectsB.prId"),
            @Mapping(target = "objectC.objectsD.objectsE.nmId", source = "objectA.objectsB.dtId")
    })
    ObjectC objectAToObjectC(ObjectA objectA);
}
```

How can I do it? Any feedback will be apreciated! Thank you!

Comment: please show us your findings for the problem that you are facing. You can create a custom mapping to map list by using `@AfterMapping`

Answer (score 3):

You have to add custom mapping method to map nested objectB to objectD and  any string to ObjectE.

This should work for you given example:

```java
@Mapper
public interface AppMapper
{
    @Mapping(source = "objectsB", target = "objectsD")
    ObjectC objectAToObjectC(ObjectA objectA);

    @Mapping(source = "prId", target = "objectE.nmId")
    @Mapping(source = "dtId", target = "objectsE")
    ObjectD objectBtoObjectD(ObjectB objectB);

}
```